# Send 5MB of data over a socket?

Tags: java, android, performance, tcp, large-data-volumes

Hi I want to send a fixed amount of data (say 5MB) from server to Android client over TCP using the Java programming language. The data doesn't matter it will be dropped at the client I am only doing this to do performance measurements on the phone.

Can anyone recommend a good way of accomplishing this? How can I have the server continually sending a large amount of data? Without the intermittent behaviour of reading a line from a file, then sending those bytes... then reading another line and sending those ones.

Ideas? Cheers.

Comment: Is the only purpose to measure the data transfer rate of the phone? Will something like [Speed Test](http://www.appbrain.com/app/speedtest-net-speed-test/org.zwanoo.android.speedtest) work?

Comment: I am actually focusing on energy efficiency. I want to see how much of the battery it takes to receive the entire transfer, and then see if I can manipulate the transfer to improve battery life, with minimal extra delay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to send a file, you could just send a block of data.

```
// server which sends 5 MB on connection.
ServerSocket ss = 
Socket s = ss.accept();
s.getOutputStream().write(new byte[5*1024*1024]);
s.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a byte array of size 1024 and loop sending it out the socket over and over. The data doesn't need to be unique. You could use a larger array if you felt a KB isn't big enough for you.

Sounds like you were asking about the server there. Were you also wondering about the client?

Comment: I am currently battling with the client. I am pretty new to Android.